# How does one round TABLE corners with JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html-table, rounded-corners

I've got a plain  html table, and I'd like to round its corners in some way that is more automated than creating a different image for each foreground/background combination. Oh, and it absolutely must work with IE7. Anyone know of such a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Rico Corner](http://demos.openrico.org/demos/corner) (requires [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/))

It's used on [SlimTimer](http://slimtimer.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice round-up of rounded corners techniques both with and without JavaScript:
[CSS Rounded Corners 'Roundup'](http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000044.php). If you're primarily targeting IE7, you'll want to avoid anything that requries CSS3. You'll also want to consider your priorities. For example, is it more important to you to have the best looking rounded corners (e.g. really good anti-aliasing) or is it more important to you to avoid a JavaScript dependency? Do you need to put rounded corners on objects whose size can change or only on objects of a fixed size?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the link. My only requirement is that the library/technique work on tables in IE7...I've tried 4 libraries already, and DD_roundies seem to be closest to what I want (but not close enough). do you know if any of the ones listed work with tables?